# Nonblocking write() goes infinitie - java

Tags: java, network-programming

I have a simple web fetcher. And the OP_WRITE trigger the selector all the time, so select() never ends. Select is always return 1, waiting for writing despite the fact that the channels has finished their job, and closed. How do i handle it? Also my CPU goes really high.

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{

try
{
    String adder="";

    Selector selector= simpleFetcher.selector;
    selector = Selector.open();

    Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");

    try{

    //add to selector the host and settings
    addHost(selector, "localhost", 80);
    addHost(selector, "site.org", 80);

    } catch (UnresolvedAddressException ex) {System.out.println("Address Not exist "+ex.getMessage());}

    while(true)
    {

    int selectedn = selector.select(2000);
    if (selectedn==0)
    {
        Set<SelectionKey> SelectorKeys = selector.keys();
        Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator  = SelectorKeys.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            SelectionKey k = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();
            SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) k.channel();

            String rHost;
            InetAddress addr = channel.socket().getInetAddress();
            rHost= addr.getHostAddress();
            System.out.println(rHost+" is timeout");

        }
        System.out.println("adder:"+adder);
        selector.close();

        System.out.println("No more keys.. Exiting");
        return;
    }

    Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
    Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator  = selectedKeys.iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();
        iterator.remove();

        if (key.isValid()==false) {System.out.println("key not valid"); continue;}


        try{
            if (key.isConnectable())
            {

                System.out.println("Will connect right now");

                SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

                if (!channel.finishConnect()) { System.out.println("Not finished connection. continue.."); continue; }
                if (channel.isConnectionPending()==false && channel.socket().isClosed()==true) System.out.println("CLOSED?");


                SelectionKey k = channel.register(key.selector(),SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                SelectionKey k2 = channel.register(key.selector(),SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                //SelectionKey k = channel.register(key.selector(),SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                k.attach(ByteBuffer.allocate(4000));


                System.out.println("Just Connected");
                continue;
            }
            if (key.isReadable())
            {
                int readB;
                System.out.println("Ready for reading..");
                SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                ByteBuffer buffer = (ByteBuffer) key.attachment();
                CharBuffer charbuffer = buffer.asCharBuffer();

                if ((readB=channel.read(buffer)) !=-1) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Key accepted - reading..");
                    int current_capacity=buffer.position();

                    buffer.flip();
                    CharBuffer c = charset.decode(buffer);
                    char[] arr = c.array();


                    String data = new String(arr);

                    String[] lines = data.split("\\r\\n\\r\\n");
                    if (lines.length>1) 
                    {
                        String header = lines[0];
                        String rest_body = lines[1];
                        //System.out.println("Header is: "+header);
                        //System.out.println("Body is: "+rest_body);
                        adder+=header+rest_body;
                    }
                    else { adder+=new String(arr); }


                }
                else 
                {
                    key.channel().close();
                    key.cancel();
                    System.out.println("Key cancled");
                    System.out.println(adder);

                    continue;
                }
                if (readB==0) System.out.println("The READ RETURNS 0");

                    System.out.println();
                    buffer.clear();

                continue;

            }
            if (key.isWritable())
            {

                //System.out.println("Ready to write");

                    SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                    String rHost;

                    Socket s = channel.socket();
                    s.shutdownOutput();



                    InetAddress addr = channel.socket().getInetAddress();
                    rHost= addr.getHostAddress();
                    //System.out.println(rHost);

                    if (s.isOutputShutdown()) continue;

                    String bytestowrite="GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "+rHost+"\r\nUser-agent: Agent 1.0 Experimental\r\nAccept: */*\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
                    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytestowrite.getBytes());

                    while(buffer.hasRemaining()) channel.write(buffer);
                    key.cancel();
                continue;
            }


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION: "+ex.getMessage());
            key.cancel(); 
            try { key.channel().close();} 
            catch (IOException cex) {}; 
        }

        System.out.println("End of iterator loop");
    }
    }
}catch (IOException ex) {System.out.println("Timeout");}



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket channels are almost always writeable, which means there is almost always space available in the socket send buffer. That only ceases to be true if the sender outruns the receiver.

So it isn't correct to register channels for `OP_WRITE` unless they have already experienced a buffer-full condition, i.e. if a write() has returned zero, and OP_WRITE should be detegistered as soon as a subsequent write has succeeded.

Comment: EJP thanks for your help again! Do you know how to avoid such problems? For example if i wrote what i needed how to stop writing? key.cancel() will do the work? 
(I have registered key for OP_READ | OP_WRITE)

Comment: I've just answered that. *Don't* register for OP_WRITE *except* in the circumstance I described. It isn't correct. See above.